# Math accents overlap in beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, accents, font-metrics

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\uselanguage{spanish}
\languagepath{spanish}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $\max \lim$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

With this MWE the math operators accents overlap:

[image]

How can I fix this in order to obtain `máx` and `lím`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are planning to use a non-default font (`lmodern`, in your case), it is advisable to use the `professionalfonts` font theme

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
```

to prevent `beamer` from doing some undesired replacements:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\uselanguage{spanish}
\languagepath{spanish}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  $\max \lim$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

According to the `beamer` manual, the following font packages don't need the explicit use of `professionalfonts`, since beamer's substitution is automatically turned off for them: `arevmath`, `hvmath`, `kpfonts`, `lucidabr`, `lucimatx`, `mathpmnt`, `mathpple`, `mathtime`, `mtpro`, and `mtpro2`. I've contacted one of the maintainers to request that `lmodern` is included in this list as well.