# I am getting a weird black square in math mode instead of "i" in symbols like \lim or \inf

Tags: beamer, math-mode, symbols

If  I write the symbol \lim in math mode in beamer I get a weird black square instead of the "i"

[image: the black square instead of the "i" in \lim]

It happen also with other symbols as \inf, but not with \sin. It seems to be related with symbols that accept subscripts below them. If the document class is article, there is no problem. By the way, I am compiling with pdflatex. Anyone has a clue of what is happening?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{frame}
 $\lim $
\end{frame} 
 
\end{document}` works fine, so please include a short example that allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Are you perhaps using `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` on a TeX Live before 2016?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the welcome. Glad to join the community, and I hope I can also give some help. With the proposed MWE, it is working fine. @egreg is right, if a set the Spanish language, then the "i" is replace by another symbol. Some other languages seems to be fine. My TeX Live is a version of 2015 included in Linux Mint 18.

Comment: After the comment by @egreg, I have been making some research and I found that by using \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} it is working right.  The problem seems to be related with the use of accents in math environment.

Comment: @Robert -- the solution you found is one i haven't seen before, so you could add a self-answer so that this question won't get deleted automatically for lack of an answer.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested, I am posting an answer to my own question. It is more likely a workaround, but it works. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212196/math-accents-overlap-in-beamer) you can find that by using `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` the problem is solved and the accents in math environment when using Spanish are correctly handled.

Thank you very much for your help.

Greetings

Robert